# Get the images dimension from html

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

I have two images in two different section and div.I want to get the original  dimension at same time and send to my java script file to do some calculation. How do I get the images dimension at the same time.

html file

```
<section id ="hi">
<img src = "images/hi.png" onload = "OnImageLoad(event);" />
</section>
<section id = "bye">
<img src = "images/hi.png" onload = "OnImageLoad(event);"/>
</section>
```

js

```
function OnImageLoad(evt) {

    var img = evt.currentTarget;

    // what's the size of this image
    var w = $(img).width();
    var h = $(img).height();
```

In this code I am able to get the images dimension of images,But they return dimension of only one images.I want to get the dimension of both images at same time.

Something like this:

```
 function OnImageLoad(evt) {

        var img1 = evt.currentTarget;
        var img2 = evt.currentTarget;

        // what's the size of this image
        var w1 = $(img1).width();
        var h1 = $(img1).height();

        var w2 = $(img2).width();
        var h2 = $(img2).height();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function OnImageLoad() {

        var img1 = document.getElementById("Image1");
        var img2 = document.getElementById("Image2");

        // what's the size of this image
        var w1 = img1.width;
        var h1 = img1.height;

        var w2 = img2.width;
        var h2 = img2.height;
}
```

Html:

```
<section id ="hi">
<img id="Image1" src = "images/hi.png"/>
</section>
<section id = "bye">
<img id="Image2" src = "images/hi.png"/>
</section>
```

Call this function on `window.onload=OnImageLoad();`

Comment: It has to be done that way as the way you did winn execute `OnImageLoad` twice..OP may not want that to happen..

Comment: I am very new to html ans frontent, where should I put window.onload = onImageLoad().I am using ember js

Comment: Call onImageLoad() on body tag which has onload as one of its attribute :)...hope u get it now :)

Comment: @MarutiNandan Got the solution??

Comment: @AkshayJ Can I get you email id.I have got stuck at some point

Comment: @MarutiNandan Where are you stuck up??..we can start a chat and discuss over your problem :)

Comment: @AkshayJ   Ok lets chat.How to start it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98228/discussion-between-maruti-nandan-and-akshayj).

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that, they are `async` tasks. You can only calculate the size of the image only when they are completely loaded, so If first image is of higher size then the second image, it will take more time to calculate the first image size then the second.

What you can do is, fetch both the image sizes aynchronously, and when both of them are done you can do the calculations.

```
var sizes = [];
var counter = 0;

function OnImageLoad(evt) {

    var img = evt.currentTarget;
    // what's the size of this image
    var w = $(img).width();
    var h = $(img).height();
    counter++;
    sizes.push({
        height: h,
        width: w
    });

    if (counter == 2) {
        callAnotherFunction(sizes)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

prepending the variables with a custom value should make it possible. 
HTML

```
<section id ="hi">
<img src = "images/hi.png" onload = "OnImageLoad(event,1);" />
</section>
<section id = "bye">
<img src = "images/hi.png" onload = "OnImageLoad(event,2);"/>
</section>
```

JS

```
function OnImageLoad(evt, pre) {

var img = evt.currentTarget;

// what's the size of this image
eval("var w" + pre + " = $(img).width()");
eval("var h" + pre + " = $(img).height()");
```

Ive not tested this though.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function OnImageLoad(evt) {
  //This function will be called on each image load and will iterate all the image inside this dom
  var images = $('img');
  for(var i =0 ;i<images.length; i++) {
        // what's the size of this image
        var w = $(images[i]).width();
        var h = $(images[i]).height();
    //For each file you will have width and height of the image
    console.log('width of image-'+i+': ',w);
    console.log('height of image-'+i+': ',h);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<section id ="hi">
<img src = "http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-glossy-green-orbs-icons-business/103491-3d-glossy-green-orb-icon-business-tool-screwdriver.png" onload = "OnImageLoad(event);" />
</section>
<section id = "bye">
<img src = "http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/3d-glossy-orange-orbs-icons-business/105429-3d-glossy-orange-orb-icon-business-tool-hammer4-sc44.png" onload = "OnImageLoad(event);"/>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

[enter link description here](http://jsbin.com/totakoseri/edit?html,js,console)

Comment: the problem with your solution is that there are many img present in html.It is gettng all the img and I don't want that.

Comment: @MarutiNandan can you tell me what are the images do you want? In your code I found two images. so I thought there may be many more images. that's the reason I made that generic to search all the images and fetch their height and width.

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34333480/get-the-dimension-of-images-placed-beside-each-other-for-calculation.You will understand

Comment: there are some design asset img tag also